# Storing Record for IP Address (DB Alternative)

Tags: php, mysql, database, ip

I need to store a record for a user per IP address to limit the rate at which a certain IP address can perform an action.

I know that storing the IP in a database would work but I am worried that on a small VPS with limited resources, too much processing power would be taken by the MySQL process. Is there another way of storing data for an IP?

I thought of a system similar to:

```
/ips/
/ips/127/
/ips/127/0
/ips/127/0/0
/ips/127/0/0/1.txt
```

Sample Code:

```
$ip_parts = explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$records = intval(file_get_contents('ips/' . implode('/', $ip_parts)));

if($records > 50) {
    echo 'Error - credits used.';
} else {
    // Do something
}
```

With the 1.txt file containing the needed data. Would I encounter issues with the number of files or folders causing this method to be slower than a database?

Comment: Don't worry about your VPS - MySQL is fine for this - done it many times.

Comment: ...or you could use [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) to avoid having to run a seperate application.

Comment: If this is a performance concern, you have much bigger problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this question / answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/221486/optimizing-mysql-for-small-vps) on ServerFault regarding DBMS optimization.  You're trying to reinvent the wheel for no particular reason (unless you won't ever use MySQL on that VPS).  And, while on the subject of storing IP addresses in MySQL, take a look at the [INET_ATOI()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) function for MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think building your own file-based database scheme is better than software build for the purpose by software engineers with 20 years of experience? Just use a MySQL database - there's rarely a case where not doing so is better - other than if you actually wish to save files.

Comment: I don't doubt that MySQL is better, I just know that it requires an extra process with its own memory requirements. When resources are tight, I look for any way to cut down.

Comment: A process that does nothing uses pretty much no resources. The resources MySQL use is for stuff that it has decided is worth doing to increase performance. Those are things such as caching and indexing. All the kind of stuff that makes your queries perform better. And by that I don't only mean give you faster results, but also decrease the workload of your harddrive by reducing IO overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a filesystem is not free either and can cause a lot of gray hair on multiple points, so I'm skeptic as to whether it would actually be better than using a database.

That said, whether you end up using files or a database, you would probably want to learn about [`ip2long`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and MySQL's equivalent [`INET_ATON`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton). Especially if you end up using MySQL, since numeric keys tend to be more efficient than strings.

Comment: I read about ip2long in another post and will probably use it if I go down the database route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sqlite? It should work well.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

Comment: Answer does not explain why this would be a better solution than the OP's proposed one, or what the benefits are.